# Angular Renderer listen() Function Not Working as Expected

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-renderer2

I'm trying to add a click event to dynamically created components, but the renderer.listen function doesn't seem to be working as expected. Here's my code:

```
updateCardTemplate(arr: CardData[]) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    const cardComponent = this.renderer.createElement("ion-card");
    cardComponent.classList.add("userCard");

    cardComponent.innerHTML = `
      <div>
        <img src="${arr[i].imgUri}">
      </div>
      <ion-card-header>
        <ion-card-title>${arr[i].username}</ion-card-title>
      </ion-card-header>
    `;

    this.renderer.appendChild(this.cards.nativeElement, cardComponent);

    // Add the click event here
    this.renderer.listen(cardComponent, 'click', () => {
      console.log("User clicked");
      this.router.navigate(["user-trainer-view"]);
    });
  }
}
```

When I click on the generated cards, nothing happens. The HTML generated for the cards looks correct, and I've checked the class 'userCard' is applied. There are no console errors, and the router is correctly configured for navigation. What could be causing this issue, and how can I fix it?

Comment: why do you not use a simple `*ngFor` in the .html?

Comment: @Eliseo i could use it but I need a function for refresh the cards

Comment: not, when change the array arr, Angular repaint it. Perhaf you should use some like `this.arr=[...this.arr]` to create a copy of the array or check if you're using a ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush, but should work (NOTE: I'm not pretty sure about ionic way to refresh, simply I imagine it's like Angular)

Comment: Wow I wouldn't recommend using `innerHTML` in Angular if you don't know what you're doing.

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler what do you mean?

Comment: Having to use the renderer is most of the time a misuse and a wrong understanding of how angular works.

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler why you wouldn't recommend using innerHTML?

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler I know what I’m doing bro, and I know that I can just use angular’s directive like *ngfor or others, but I’m telling you I need a function for do it

Comment: Is your callback logged ?

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler i've added a console log in the callback but when i click the item dont appear in console